12 V USB 4 channel relay controlling
I’m trying to control a relay using Python, but I’ve hit a roadblock.
Unfortunately, I couldn’t find the datasheet for this specific relay, which means I don’t have the correct commands to send.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
The computer recognizes the device as an HID (Human Interface Device).
I’ve attempted various commands, but none seem to work.
I tried this code, but I got an error because my relay didn't take any commands:
import hid

def list_hid_devices():
    for device in hid.enumerate():
        keys = list(device.keys())
        keys.sort()
        for key in keys:
            print(f"{key}: {device[key]}")
        print()

def send_hid_command(vendor_id, product_id, command):
    try:
        device = hid.device()
        device.open(vendor_id, product_id)
        
        print(f"Manufacturer: {device.get_manufacturer_string()}")
        print(f"Product: {device.get_product_string()}")
        print(f"Serial No: {device.get_serial_number_string()}")
        
        device.write(command)
        
        response = device.read(64)
        print(f"Response: {response}")

        device.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


print(" HID devices:")
list_hid_devices()

VENDOR_ID = 0x16C0  
PRODUCT_ID = 0x05DF  
relay_commands = [
    [0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], 
    [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],  
]

for command in relay_commands:
    send_hid_command(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID, command)

My terminal is like this:
Manufacturer: www.dcttech.com
Product: USBRelay4
Serial No:
Error: read error
Manufacturer: www.dcttech.com
Product: USBRelay4
Serial No:
Error: read error
Does anyone know the right commands for controlling this relay?
Where can I find the datasheet for this relay?

I haven't used that particular relay board, but I'd suggest this as a starting point :
https://sigrok.org/wiki/Dcttech_usbrelay
And this page it links to :
http://vusb.wikidot.com/project:driver-less-usb-relays-hid-interface
These suggest the interface is based on V-USB, and you should set the relays using USB HID's Set Feature Report.
If you look into the associated github repository, you can find the meat of the C implementation at https://github.com/pavel-a/usb-relay-hid/blob/master/commandline%2Fusbrelay-cmd.c#L212-L258
Based on the code there, it would seem the commands you are looking for are all sent as feature reports to feature 0, with the following data:
ALL ON : 0xFE
ALL OFF : 0xFC
ONE On : 0xFF <relaynum>
ONE Off : 0xFD <relaynum>

Depending on the particular python libraries you are using, you'll have to work out how to send those USB HID commands.
Assuming you've simply done a pip install hid to get whatever you're importing with import hid, you may wish to try device.send_feature_report with, for example, [0x00, 0xFE] to turn all relays on.

This helped me get one of these boards working using HidSharp. The assertion made by the usb-relay-hid developer that the boards have a unique identifier does not seem be universally true: my two boards have the same value.

This relay is not working in windows 11 (if anyone encountered this problem)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
